# python using Selenium to download files

Tags: python, selenium

guys I need to write a script that use selenium to go over the pages on the website and download each page to a file.
This is the website I need to go through and I wanna download all 10 pages of reviews.
This is my code:

```
import urllib2,os,sys,time
from selenium import webdriver

browser=urllib2.build_opener()
browser.addheaders=[('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]



url='http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2948356/reviews?ref_=tt_urv'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(2)


if not os.path.exists('reviewPages'):os.mkdir('reviewPages')

response=browser.open(url)
myHTML=response.read()
fwriter=open('reviewPages/'+str(1)+'.html','w')
fwriter.write(myHTML)
fwriter.close()
print 'page 1 done'

page=2

while True:
    cssPath='#tn15content > table:nth-child(4) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(11) > img'
    try:
        button=driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cssPath)
    except:
        error_type, error_obj, error_info = sys.exc_info()
        print 'STOPPING - COULD NOT FIND THE LINK TO PAGE: ', page
        print error_type, 'Line:', error_info.tb_lineno
        break

    button.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    response=browser.open(url)
    myHTML=response.read()
    fwriter=open('reviewPages/'+str(page)+'.html','w')
    fwriter.write(myHTML)
    fwriter.close()
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'page',page,'done'
    page+=1
```

But the program just stop downloading the first page. Could someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So a few things that are causing this.

Your first I think that's causing you issues is:

```
table:nth-child(4)
```

When I go to that website, I think you just want:

```
table >
```

The second error is the break statement in your except message.  This says, when I get an error, stop looping.

So what's happening is your try, except is not working because your CSS selector is not quite correct, and going to your exception where you are telling it to stop looping.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that very complex CSS path try this simpler xpath ('//a[child::img[@alt="[Next]"]]/@href') which will return the URL associated with the little triangular 'next' button on each page.

**Or** notice that each page has 10 reviews  and the URLs for pages 2 to 10 just give the start review number, ie http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2948356/reviews?start=10 which is the URL for page 2. Simply calculate the URL for the next page and stop when it doesn't fetch anything.